# How do I delay a NavLink in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

```
Delay = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTimeout(() => {
        e.unpreventDefault() //make this work
    },500)
}

render() {
    <NavLink
        to='/About'
        onClick={this.Delay}
    >
        Delay Me!
    </NavLink>
}
```

After clicking the NavLink, I want to wait 500ms before going to '/About'. How do I do that?

Edit: I want to use the NavLink activeStyle attribute

Comment: one option is don't use NavLink, use any other element and onClick of that do `history.push` after 500ms.

Comment: I want to use the NavLink activeStyle attribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, wrap your compoent use `withRouter` .[Doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

withRouter(Component)
```

Then use `this.props.history.push('/About')`to navigate in your Delay function. [Doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)

```
Delay = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/About')
    },500)
}
```