# How to make React Router NavLink wait for state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to pass the value of a state along with the location used by NavLink.

The value used to update the state is being got from an `input`, therefore I need to wait for the state to be updated before NavLink redirect the component.

How can I do that?

A sample of my code:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react'

import './Layout.css'

import { NavLink as RRNavLink, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"

    class Layout extends Component {
    
        state = {
            searchProduct: false,
            input: ''
        }
    
    
        searchProductHandler = e => {
            let inputValue = e.currentTarget.parentNode.childNodes[0].value
            
            if (inputValue.length >= 3) {
                this.setState({
                    searchProduct: true, 
                    input: inputValue
                })
                
            } else {
                alert('Digite ao menos 3 letras no campo de busca')
            }
    
        }
    
    
    
        render () {
            return (
    
                <Fragment>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input />
                                <NavLink 
                                    onClick={this.searchProductHandler} 
                                    to={"/search/" + this.state.input}>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon 
                                            icon="search" 
                                            color="grey" 
                                            style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} 
                                        />
                                </NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
                    <main>
                        {
                            this.props.children
                        }
                    </main>
                </Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default Layout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fire your searchProductHandler function on the onchange event of the input.

i.e.

```
 <input onChange={this.searchProductHandler}/>
```

This way your state will have the proper value when clicking the search button.

Comment: Excellent idea. It works in this particular case. But at any rate, do you know how to delay `NavLink`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853582/how-do-i-delay-a-navlink-in-react